# Why do I need the index parameter in a function, when going through objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

In the getFullName function, why do I need the index parameter?

This example code is from W3 School http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_map3

EDIT: Apparently I don't need it. In what type of case would I need it? Or is that even relevant to ask in this context?

```js
    var persons = [
        {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
        {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
        {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
    ];


    function getFullName(item,index) {
        var fullname = [item.firstname,item.lastname].join(" ");
        return fullname;
    }

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  persons.map(getFullName);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to get a new array with the full name of each person in the array.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p>New array: <span id="demo"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Why do I need the index parameter in a function, when going through objects in an array?

Comment: You don't! Did you just try removing it

Comment: Should be noted that `map` returns an array, and setting an array as innerHTML is generally not the best idea

Comment: More importantly, why do you *think* you need it? Did you see something that led you to that conclusion?

Comment: @squint Trying to learn, and found that example on W3 school website.

Comment: @Suomi w3schools.com is not the greatest site, they have lots of mistakes like that. They're trying to be complete and make the function take all the arguments that `.map()` sends, but they forgot that it also sends the array itself as the third argument.

Comment: @Suomi: I see. Yes, the parameters to functions *never* need to be defined. That may seem strange, but it's true. If you don't want to use parameters, then you can simply leave them off. If, for example, you wanted to use the second param, you'd need to also define the first, and just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just design of the `map` function, May be you don't need the `index` at this scenario but there might be scenario like, `If its 3rd element update the data else do nothing!!`.  At such scenarios you make use of the `index`.

You can just neglect it from the function definition if don't require it.

```
function getFullName(item){
//..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need it. Since you don't use it, you can remove it if you want.

```js
var persons = [
  {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
  {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
  {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
function getFullName(item) {
  var fullname = [item.firstname,item.lastname].join(" ");
  return fullname;
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.map(getFullName);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get a new array with the full name of each person in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>New array: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

The only difference is that `getFullName.length` will be `1` instead of `2`.